# Hosting WebMatrix Page

Tags: webmatrix

What exactly do I need from a host for my webmatrix project to work? I know Scott Hanselman from Microsoft gave out a few nice host sites but I was just wondering for fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to publish to a host from WebMatrix using Web Deploy, the host needs to be in a compliant state. First of all, it has to run WebDeploy and the remote service WMSvc has to be in a desired state (enabled and started). [Delegation rules](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/) have to be set up, so that the user has permissions and the right scope to deploy various components like IIS application, database, ACLs, etc. In order to check whether a host is WebMatrix-friendly, [ServerValidator tool](http://blogs.iis.net/bilalaslam/archive/2010/12/03/servervalidator-a-tool-to-validate-your-server-s-configuration.aspx) can be used (see the article for a full list of host requirements).

If you want to publish to a host though FTP, all you need to ensure is that FTP publishing is enabled on the host.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any .Net 4.0 host, but you'll need to copy a bunch of DLL files to yuor `bin` folder.

The exact files required depend on what libraries your site uses.
At a minimum, you'll probably need

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
- WebMatrix.Data.dll
- WebMatrix.WebData.dll

These can be found in `Program Files\Microsoft ASP.Net`.

If it still doesn't work, copy any additional files from FileNotFound errors.

Comment: WebMatrix actually deploys these anyway. I think what he was really asking was "what should a host be offering if I want to use WebMatrix and the WebDeploy feature"...which does a bunch of clever stuff like file sync and database deployment. That's the stuff that Hanselman has been pushing in his recent demos & blog entries.

Answer (score 0):

To publish your website from WebMatrix - your hosting provider must support one of the two publishing technologies - FTP and/or WebDeploy.

In case of FTP, you would need to manually enter the following ftp settings: FTP Server, username, password and destination url. Optionally you can also specify the site path

In case of WebDeploy, you could just get the publishsettings file for your host and import the settings. Else, you can also manually enter these settings.