# Webconfig error with the site online

Tags: web-config, publish, webmatrix

I'm trying to publish a [web site](http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/).

The publication works perfectly, but when I try to access the address it returns me the following error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Web.Helpers' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built
>   by a runtime newer than the currently
>   loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 293:                    
>   Line 294:                    
>   Line 295:                     Line 296:
>    Line
>   297:
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config
>   Line: 295
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'Microsoft.Web.Helpers' could not be
>   loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

This does not happen when I'm running on the local site.

The application was developed and Sql Server WebMatrix Compac 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error message it says "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is ***built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime*** and cannot be loaded." If you then look at the version of the ASP.NET that this site is attempting to run under, it is ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4209.

Web Pages and the Web Helpers library need Version 4.0. Make sure the site targets the correct version of ASP.NET.

Comment: Understood.

Now I have a problem, the contractor bears to the host. net 3.5.

Comment: Yep - you have a problem. Get them to install 4.0, change hosting, or rewrite using something that targets pre-4.0.

Comment: I contacted them and they have to support 4.0.
But for some reason the site is running with the framework 3.5 (or 2.0).
See: http://amsdarquitetura.com.br/

Comment: Did you make sure the right options were selected in the Settings prior to publishing?

Comment: Yes, I checked the options and this is entirely correct.
On the error page, footer, has the following information:
Version Information: Microsoft. NET Framework Version: 2.0.50727.4206; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.4209

So I think the host is not using. net 4.0

Comment: +1  Good answer Mike we all missed the runtime version and were trying to solve the missing assembly problem which doesn't exist.  well spotted

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your web.config is fine and that there  is an assembly missing from your deployment.

You probably have to include microsoft.web.helpers in your deployment package or simply copy it to the bin folder.

You might find that there are other assemblies missing but you should be able to pick them off one by one.

There is a previous question [Hosting WebMatrix Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846352/hosting-webmatrix-page)

that lists all of the dlls you have to deploy and also suggests using Webdeploy

Comment: in my bin folder, the file has already Microsoft.Web.Helpers.dll

Comment: the folder structure on my host is:

"/site/web/bin"
   
"/site/web/*FILES"

The dll mentioned is just the bin, I checked it.

Comment: All dlls are cited in the bin folder.
I moved the bin to the root folder but still did not work
Please visit http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/ and see the error.

Comment: does that line really say <add assembly="*" />  I don't think i have ever seen that before. Try removing that from the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

For missing assemblies a simple solution is to just bundle them with your project.
Go to your project -> references -> find this microsoft web helpers ref -> open the properties panel and set `Copy Local` to **True**

Edit: Also try setting assembly binding logging.

Comment: Sorry but what is: setting assembly binding logging.

I'm using, WebMatrix.

The dll mentioned is in the bin folder, I checked it.

Comment: The problem might be some other library (a dependency). Try brute-forcing (setting all references to CopyLocal **True** and redeploy).

Comment: how can I do this in WebMatrix?

Please visit http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/ and see the error.

Comment: To enable logging you must change a registry setting, as described by the bottom message (_To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1._). Did you try setting all CopyLocal to True ?

Comment: I do not know how to do this in WebMatrix.
In Visual Studio's okay, I only wish to select which reference the properties and mark it as a copy to local, but we do not have WebMatrix properties window and references window.